# Intellij import maven project fails with sshuttle on

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, tunnel

I am trying to import a maven based project in IntelliJ.

I can only partially resolve dependences if I am not connected to another host (call it `dev-serv`) with lies on a less secure network.

I use `sshuttle` to create tunnel between my computer and `dev-serv` with the following command :

```
sshuttle --dns -vr dev-serv -x LOCAL_NETWORK 0.0.0.0/0 -x 127.0.0.1/8
```

When I try to import the project using IntelliJ, clicking "next" does nothing on the import screen, and IntelliJ logs record an exception :.

> 2017-12-11 16:47:05,983 [  18630]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3  Build #IU-173.3727.127
>
> 2017-12-11 16:47:05,983 [  18630]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release
>
> 2017-12-11 16:47:05,983 [  18630]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
>
> 2017-12-11 16:47:05,983 [  18630]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o
>
> 2017-12-11 16:47:05,983 [  18630]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X
>
> 2017-12-11 16:47:05,983 [  18630]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:
>
> 2017-12-11 16:47:25,937 [  38584]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - java.rmi.NotBoundException: _DEAD_HAND_
>
> 2017-12-11 16:47:25,938 [  38585]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:209)
>
> 2017-12-11 16:47:25,938 [  38585]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer.start(RemoteServer.java:92)
>
> 2017-12-11 16:47:25,938 [  38585]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer.main(RemoteMavenServer.java:22)
>
> 2017-12-11 16:48:18,021 [  90668]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - The cook failed to start due to java.io.EOFException
>
> 2017-12-11 16:48:18,027 [  90674]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot reconnect.
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect.
>       at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:82)

Importing the projet to IntelliJ without sshuttle running works fine (but some dependences are not resolved).

The project can be compiled and run fine using maven on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to [a bug in sshuttle v0.78.3](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle/issues/164#event-1223187405) with MacOs firewall (pf). This [is solved in v0.78.4 - UNRELEASED](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#fixed) of [sshuttle](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle).

To install the correct version of [sshuttle](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle) :

```
git clone https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle.git
cd sshuttle
python3 -m venv .
source bin/activate
./setup.py install
```

To run sshuttle :

```
deactivate
./bin/sshuttle mysshuser@mysshserver
```

Hope it can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem related to networking and address resolution. In some cases localhost may not resolve and it's required to have

`127.0.0.1 localhost`

in /etc/hosts file. Also make sure there are no other IP addresses mapped to localhost.

Comment: Indeed @y.bedrov, thanks, that lead me to this link https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000001790/comments/115000004284 and also this one : https://superuser.com/questions/1238431/how-to-stop-sshuttle-from-forwarding-localhost It is due to a buggy redirection of requests to localhost in sshuttle v0.78.3 (current release). v0.78.4 (develop branch) fixes it.